# How to send messages on a scheduled basis in Netty?

Tags: android, kotlin, netty

I want to send messages per 10 seconds with Netty framework.

Therefore, I use a IdleStateHandler to send heart beat msgs on a scheduled basis:

```kotlin
class ClientHeartBeatHandler(readerIdleTime: Long, writerIdleTime: Long, allIdleTime: Long):
    IdleStateHandler(readerIdleTime, writerIdleTime, allIdleTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS) {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun channelIdle(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, evt: IdleStateEvent) {
        if (evt.state() == IdleState.WRITER_IDLE ) {
            XLog.i("Time to send message")
        }
        else if(evt.state() == IdleState.READER_IDLE) {
            XLog.e("PTZMessenger TCP Connection LOST")
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I send other messages, the time to send heart beat msg will be reset. For example, I send a heart beat msg at 00:00:00. If I send other msg at 00:00:05, the next heart beat msg will be sent  at 00:00:15, although it should be sent at 00:00:10. How to fix the problem, Any ideas?